# What is the better way to draw waveform in silverlight?

Tags: performance, silverlight, graphics, line, waveform

i am making an application in silverlight 3.0. In that application i have to draw live waveform.(Means i am drawing live data(collection of points) from my server at the rate of 4 samples per second.) So within second i have to refresh the screen four time.Means i have to redraw the grid and waveform four times within a second as i have to move grid also.
   Right now i am using collection of line of size is equal to the screen size.and drawing each and every line from that collection. But if the screen size is large then collection of line is also bigger.So it affects the performance of application. I cant use "Polyline"as i have to change the color of line at any point depending upon the data.I am not getting any effective solution.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean to say u want something like this?
http://www.stockanalysischarts.com/

Comment: @vaibhav  :Ya i have to draw the same waveform but i have to show the continuous moving of waveform as for every second i am getting data.

Comment: I gues the control you are looking for, is `Path`

Comment: @vaibhav Thanks for reply but i my line is not of single color and i have to show continuous movement of line(Waveform).

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, the best control to be implemented in your code is `Path`

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) link will help you out in understanding `Path`

And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) link shows about the syntax and rules to follow while using `Path`

You can easily change the size, shape, way, fill color,stroke thickness, etc. properties of the `Path`.
Long way to go, hope this helps!

Comment: At first, I was going to suggest [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104820/Drawing-Trig-Functions-via-WPF) to you, but you want to avoid `PolyLine` so didn't recommend you about this.